# These is the divisibility rule by 4, 25, 100?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> I need to find the divisibility rule by 4, 25 and 100. I want to know if my answer it is correct!

Knowing that:
\begin{align}
100\equiv0\mod4, \mod 25 , \mod100 \to \\
10^2 \equiv 0 \mod 4 , \mod25, \mod100
\end{align}

So, for n $\ge 2$, we have:
\begin{align}
a_210^2 \equiv 0 \mod4, \mod25, \mod100 \to\\
a_n10^n \equiv0 \mod4, \mod25, \mod100 
\end{align}

For $a =a_na_{n-1}...a_2a_1a_0$ in base 10, we have that $a \equiv 10a_1+a_0 \mod4, \mod25, \mod100 $, for to be divisibily for 4, 25, 100. In other words, $a_1a_0 = 0.$

Comment: That rule works for $100$ but I expect you are meant to come up with three rules, one for $100$, one for $25$ and one for $4$.  Note that divisibility by $100$ implies the other two so that one must be the hardest test to pass.

Comment: @lulu, I see... but The assignment asks a divisibility rule for the 3 in the same time

Comment: Well, of course I have no idea what the assignment is.  But it seems weird to add $4,25$ as if they were separate conditions.  Anyway, it is easy to find the rules for $4$ and $25$ separately so it's a good exercise.

Comment: I got it, thank you.

Comment: @lulu: They still work out to the same thing, though: Take the two last digits alone and check if they're a multiple of 4/25/100.

Comment: @HenningMakholm  Oh, absolutely.